# Motor Driver L6203 Questions

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, datasheet, st, motordriver

Hello I am a beginner trying to use the L6203 motor driver.
I am working while looking at the L6203 data sheet, and I am trying to make a circuit as shown in the picture below. However, I am curious about the type and exact capacity of the capacitor used in the picture below. Thank you very much.
[image]

Comment: Ah, they are just the ordinary caps for decoupling/bypassing. Any ceremic cap with approx values can do.  The datasheet does no mention it, because they think although it is important, but value not critical. (!) L6203 DMOS Full Bridge Motor Driver - ST
https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6203.pdf.

Comment: This is a good article on bypass/decoupling capacitors: (2) Clean Power for Every IC, Part 1: Understanding Bypass Capacitors - Robert Keim 2015sep21
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/clean-power-for-every-ic-part-1-understanding-bypass-capacitors/. Happy reading. Cheers.

Comment: BTW, L6203 can do high voltage, high power motor driving. But for newbies, I would recommend low voltage drivers such as the very popular L298N.